# username on posts not updated after profile information update in Node.js/mongoosedb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I am using Mongoose with express.js and will like to update user information across all instances.
When user updates their profile information, it gets updated on their profile document in the mongoose database. However, their username has refused to be updated on their posts. I need their username updated across all instances including their post username. Thank you for the help

I know I am not doing something right.
Here are my codes:

```
//user updates profile information

router.put("/:id", async (req, res) =>{
if(req.body.userId === req.params.id){//we checked if the user id matched
 if(req.body.password){
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
        }
        try{
       const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{ 
               $set: req.body,
           }, {new: true});  //findbyidandupdate is an inbuilt method
        res.status(200).json(updatedUser)
    } catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err) //this handles the error if there is one from the server
    }
   } else{
   res.status(401).json("You can only update your account!")
    }

         });
```

**User updates post codes**

```
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) =>{
//find post that will be updated

try{
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
     if(post.username == req.body.username )
        try{
                const updatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, 
                    $set: req.body
                }, {new: true})//this makes it possible to see the updated post
                    
                res.status(200).json(updatedPost)
        }catch(err){
            res.status(401).json(err)
            }
     } else{
         res.status(401).json("you can only update your posts")

     }

   
}catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err)
}

});
```

**User model**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    profilePicture:{
        type: String,
        default: "",
    },
  }, {timestamps: true}
);
//exporting this schema
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema); //the module name is "User"
```

**Post model**

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true, 
    },
    postPhoto:{
        type: String,
        required:false,
    },
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    categories:{
        type: Array,
        required: false
        
    },
   
  }, {timestamps: true}
 );
/ /exporting this schema
module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema); //the module name is "Post"
```

**where I used it in React.js for profile update**

```
  const handleUpdate = async (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();

  dispatch({type: "UPDATE_START"})
  const updatedUser = {
    userId: user._id,
    username,
    email,
    password
  };

 try{
  
   const response = await axios.put("/users/" + user._id, updatedUser)
     
     dispatch({type: "UPDATE_SUCCESS", payload: response.data})
     setUpdated(true)
   
  
}catch(err){
   
}
```

}

**Where I used it in React.js for post update**

```
   //this function handles the update of the post by the user
     const handleUpdate = async () =>{
      try{
            await axios.put(`/posts/${post._id}`, {
                username: user.username, 
                title:title, 
                description: description
                });
             // window.location.reload("/")
             setUpdateMode(false)
    }catch(err){

    }
   }
```

Comment: could you provide result of your api call ?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I am actually starting out with node. Please, could you clarify what you're asking of me?

Comment: when you hit `PUT /:id` wahts the response of your API ?